# NodeJS : Right-To-Left Language Console Log (Arabic)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arabic, right-to-left

I have the following tiny nodejs script which just console logs an arabic verb:

```
var verb = "كتب";
console.log(verb);
```

However, the console log gives me: output: `بتك` 
- which is the verb, but inverted. (So instead of getting `abc` I get `cba`).

I guess that this is because nodejs does not know that I am using a right-to-left language, such as Arabic. However, I was not able to find anything online, on how to fix this? Is there some setting I don't know of?

PS: What's interesting is also, that while the letters are inverted, their their form is basically correct - so the first letter, although displayed at the end, still has the correct form of a *first* letter in Arabic (in Arabic, letters take on different forms, depending on the position in the word)

[image]

Comment: I think its only because your terminal lacks the support of Arabic.  I tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Although i am not sure why it is doing that (i cant reproduce it in chrome console).

You could try reverse the string before output like so:

```
var verb = "كتب";
console.log(verb.split("").reverse().join(""));
```

Comment: for Persian or Arabic alphabet, It will return 'ک ت ب' which is wrong

Comment: Well yes because this was a answer for his specific problem. Its a simple string reverse.

Comment: its a problem if the string includes numbers like dates, 2021 -> 1202

Answer (score 1):

Bro it's just because of the console , your word will still conserved as it is if you try to send it in the response object for testing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a package on npm for displaying the Arabic text correctly on consoles/terminals that don't support it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtl-arabic